# How to loop the ajax call for pdf file download?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
if( $.isArray(certTypeReq) ){                
    $.each(certTypeReq,function(key,certType){
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl+"/user/certificate/getlink",
            type: 'GET',
            data: { 'certType' : certType},
            dataType : 'json',
            cache: false,
            async:false,
            success: function(data) {    
            window.location.href = data.link;
            }
        });
    });            
}
```

This is my code and its working fine in Firefox but not in chrome browser. If anyone has solution please help me.

Comment: Is Chrome raising any error in the dev tools? Maybe a security warning?

Comment: Don't using `async: false`.

Comment: What happens and what should happen?

Comment: @SLaks, true, but jQuery ignores it and if he uses a old version that will be the problem because Chrome does not allow synchronous calls.

Comment: Probably a security question

Comment: Chrome is not raising any error. Its downloading one file only in the array loop. It should download a file for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=1;
if( $.isArray(certTypeReq) ){                
$(certTypeReq).each(function(key,certType){
  setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl+"/user/certificate/getlink",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'certType' : certType},
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data) {    
        window.location.href = data.link;
        }
    });
  }, 3000*i);                
i++;
});            
}
```

Applied delay in each iteration and it worked.

Thanks to all for your replies.